# Use SQL functions in Doctrine native queries

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I want to use the SUM function in a Doctrine native query but I keep getting empty results. Here is my code:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit', 'v');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('counter', 'counter');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('created_at', 'created_at');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery(
        'SELECT SUM(counter) FROM visits GROUP BY created_at', 
        $rsm
    );
```

Is interesting because if I don't use the SUM function the code will work:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit', 'v');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('counter', 'counter');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('created_at', 'created_at');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery(
        'SELECT counter FROM visits GROUP BY created_at', 
        $rsm
    );
```

Can someone figures out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$repository = $em->getRepository('AndreiStatisticsBundle:Visit');
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v');
$qb->select('SUM(v.counter) AS counterSum');
$qb->groupBy('v.created_at');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: I get an [Semantical Error] line 0, col 31 near 'FROM Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Visit': Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined.

Comment: Can you post the output of $qb->getQuery()->getDQL(); ?

Comment: "SELECT SUM(v.counter) AS count FROM Andrei\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Visit v GROUP BY v.created_at"

Comment: Ah, `AS count` is wrong, we can't use keywords in the DQL. I edited my answer

Comment: Can you edit your response to select multiple values, let's say select also created_at?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured our. I will edit your answer :) Thanks again!